# How to ensure_index in Production Code?

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, tornado, pymongo

How can I add an index in production code? I have found only the way to add it as a command and not embedded in a complete code:

If you want to add indexing to speed queries:

```
db.users.ensure_index(the_key)
```

So I tried to add it to a class:

```
class Registration(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        # do stuff to get user information using the self.get_argument()
        user={"all information":informations}
        self.db.users.insert(user, w=1)
        self.db.users.ensure_index(pseudo, commune)
```

But I get errors like this:

```
self.db.users.ensure_index(pseudo, commune)
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pymongo\collection.py", line 829, in ensure_index
      return self.create_index(key_or_list, cache_for, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pymongo\collection.py", line 740, in create_index
    self.__name, name, cache_for)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pymongo\connection.py", line 330, in _cache_index
    expire = datetime.timedelta(seconds=cache_for) + now
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: unicode
```

And I guess it will be the same tip when using inserting a sub-document:

```
self.db.users.update({"email":email}, {"$push":{"produit_up":{"id":id, "namep":namep, "nombre":nombre}}})
self.db.users.ensure_index("product_up.namep") #????
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got the answer:

> No No, ensureIndex is the same as creating an index. It does nothing 
>   special, maybe the name of the function is a little odd really and should 
>   be called create_index instead. 
>   Since Mongo has no pre-defined schema (NoSQL) it has to create indexes a 
>   different way to SQL. The way proposed was through client side when the 
>   user decides they need an index on a particular field. This is how 
>   collections and what not are created, when they are used by the client. 
>   This function was called ensureIndex(). 
>   So there is only one call needed to ensureIndex() within your app and it 
>   should be a list of fields for that index as the first param and any extra 
>   options (like sparse) for the second param. 
>   There is no work needed by the administrator to keep this index intact, 
>   well not once a month but if something fails in the cluster then yea, some 
>   work will be needed by the admin to possibly remake the index. 
>   I personally have a file of indexes I call everytime my app is loaded. 
>   I hope this clears things up a little,

answer from [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/af10a24d818e5f99)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is the result of passing a non-integer as `cache_for`, which tells `pymongo` how long to cache the fact that the index exists for.

I don't know what `psuedo` or `commune` in your code are, but the correct usage for `ensure_index` in `pymongo` is `ensure_index(key_or_list, cache_for=300, **kwargs)`. You can read more about this in the [pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index) but the gist of it is that `key_or_list` is either a string naming a key (yes, this can include sub-documents the way that you showed) or a list of tuples containing (key, direction) pairs with direction being `pymongo.ASCENDING` or `pymongo.DESCENDING`.

Comment: thank you, but the problem i was seeking, is where to use this function, and i've got the answer: it's kind of admin tool that it should me used only once a time (the next time it will be use, it's for repair) ;)